# Qual è il senso dell'espressione "li abbia in buona parte dormiti e giocati" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Su quanto abbia fatto Barbabramín durante questi anni, le versioni divergono. Non c’è dubbio che **li abbia in buona parte dormiti e giocati**: si sa con certezza che andò in rovina economicamente, perché «non tagliava i cupòn» dei buoni del Tesoro, e perché aveva affidato l’amministrazione delle cascine ad un mamsér («bastardo») che le aveva vendute per un boccone di pane ad un suo uomo di paglia; secondo i presagi della zia Milca, lo zio trascinò cosí nella sua rovina l’intero parentado, ed ancora oggi se ne lamentano le conseguenze.
>   
>         Si narra anche che abbia letto e studiato, e che, ritenuto infine sapiente e giusto, ricevesse dal suo letto delegazioni dei notabili di Chieri e dirimesse controversie; si narra ancora che, [...].

Su questo personaggio, Barbabramín, si spiega in precedenza:

> Ancor giovane era già molto ricco, avendo acquistato dai nobili del luogo numerose cascine da Chieri fino all’Astigiano; facendo conto sulla sua eredità, i suoi parenti sperperarono tutti i loro averi in banchetti, balli e viaggi a Parigi.

Non riesco a capire del tutto bene il senso dell'espressione "li abbia in buona parte dormiti e giocati" riferendosi agli anni trascorsi, anche se capisco che la conseguenza è che Barbabramín finí in rovina. Significa che impiegava parte del suo tempo nel gioco? E con "dormiti" si dà magari a intendere che spendeva molti soldi in prostitute? O devo semplicemente capire che consumava parte del suo tempo a dormire (questo non gli avrebbe certamente fatto perdere dei soldi, ma si tratta di un'attività non utile all'amministrazione dei suoi beni)? O magari qualcos'altro?

Comment: Letteralmente il senso è che quegli anni li ha passati dormendo e giocando. Dormiti probabilmente nel  senso di non essersi dato da fare (poltrendo). Giocati penso di riferisca al gioco d’azzardo o al Casino’.

Comment: In effetti il senso non è chiarissimo. Penso che "dormiti" sia da intendere in senso letterale, con la conseguenza della rovina economica. Per "giocati", noto che poco più avanti del testo che @Charo ha riportato, Levi scrive " si narra che [...] almeno nei primi anni la volontaria clausura dello zio fosse interrotta da sortite notturne per andare a giocare a bigliardo nel caffè di sotto". Escluderei l'ipotesi delle prostitute: il verbo dormire, da solo, e per di più riferito agli anni, non evoca rapporti sessuali.

Comment: Per quel che può valere, Ann Goldstein, traduttrice in inglese del _Sistema periodico_ e di altre opere di Levi, rende l'inizio di questo passo così: “Of what Barbabramín did during these years different stories are told. Certainly he spent a good part of them sleeping and gambling; it is known with certainty that he was ruined financially...”

Comment: @DaG:  La [traduzione in spagnolo di Carmen Martín Gaite](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=ccT4AgAAQBAJ&q=%C3%A9poca#v=snippet&q=Barbabram%C3%ADn&f=false) è abbastanza fedele all'originale italiano: «No cabe duda de que fueron años que en gran parte se los jugó y se los durmió. Se sabe con certeza que acabó en la ruina, porque [...]».

Comment: @Charo: Interessante. Quei due verbi spagnoli funzionano come in italiano? Cioè sono solitamente intransitivi (in realtà, ora che ci penso, “giocare” ha vari usi transitivi in italiano).

Comment: @Hachi: Se la ricerca scientifica ti sembra un volo pindarico, non ti importuno più.

Comment: @DaG: Possono essere transitivi, ma certamente "jugar los años" o "dormir los años" sono espressioni insolite. Si può dire, per esempio, "jugar una carta, un partido, un papel, ..." o "dormir la siesta, al niño, la mona, ..." ("mona" è un termine colloquiale per indicare ubriachezza).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108936/discussion-on-question-by-charo-qual-e-il-senso-dellespressione-li-abbia-in-bu).

Comment: @Hachi Per favore non usare i commenti ad una domanda per discutere di policy, piuttosto [chiedi una domanda su meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Per quel che vale, non concordo con la tua opinione che domande come questa verrebbero chiuse su altri siti di SE dedicati alle lingue, ma ne possiamo discutere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il senso è secondo me quello indicato da @Hachi nel suo commento;

è uno strano costrutto in cui i due verbi sono forzati a diventare transitivi per rendere l'espressione più "colorita" e rafforzare il concetto che il personaggio ha sprecato i suoi anni, piuttosto che utilizzare un più convenzionale:

> "[...] abbia passato buona parte di quegli anni dormendo e giocando [...]"

Mi ricorda un anacoluto, ma non sono sicuro si possa classificare così.